# i have been using scikit-learn on jupyterlab for my project bacause i use agglomerativeclustering but two days it has stopped working

Tags: scikit-learn

$pip install scikit-learn

WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000140060D49E0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /packages/76/d8/02fa68de37f657e6bb241e6f9ec6240bafa43222d3ef836a248145d9548f/scikit_learn-1.4.1.post1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=3, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000140060D4C80>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /packages/76/d8/02fa68de37f657e6bb241e6f9ec6240bafa43222d3ef836a248145d9548f/scikit_learn-1.4.1.post1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=2, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000140060D4D10>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /packages/76/d8/02fa68de37f657e6bb241e6f9ec6240bafa43222d3ef836a248145d9548f/scikit_learn-1.4.1.post1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=1, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000140060D4FB0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /packages/76/d8/02fa68de37f657e6bb241e6f9ec6240bafa43222d3ef836a248145d9548f/scikit_learn-1.4.1.post1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata
WARNING: Retrying (Retry(total=0, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000140060D51C0>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed')': /packages/76/d8/02fa68de37f657e6bb241e6f9ec6240bafa43222d3ef836a248145d9548f/scikit_learn-1.4.1.post1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='files.pythonhosted.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /packages/76/d8/02fa68de37f657e6bb241e6f9ec6240bafa43222d3ef836a248145d9548f/scikit_learn-1.4.1.post1-cp312-cp312-win_amd64.whl.metadata (Caused by NewConnectionError('<pip._vendor.urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x00000140060D5310>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 11002] getaddrinfo failed'))

i want to install scikit-learn since it stopped working i uninstalled and to reinstall then started facing the error message above

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.